# iOS Push Notifications - No Message Received

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have a push notification server wrote with php apns. The app has both development and production push certificates enabled and has a valid provisioning profile created after the push service was enabled.

During testing (sandbox), the push notifications send absolutely fine to the device using the development push certificate pem file after creating it using a few steps.

I submitted the app to the app store and then updated the php apns server to use the production push certificate pem file that has been created and it says connected to apple, sending message and then disconnected (as it does in the test environment) however no push notification arrives on the app (the version downloaded from the app store).

I have confirmed that the app is sending the device ID to the php apns server and the php apns server is using the correct certificates (as it connects fine - tested with an invalid cert and it failed to connect) and it says sending message however as mentioned, nothing arrives.

Does anybody have any idea why this could happen?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you get notifications into your app using the Apple production server, profiles and certs but in your development environment - before submitting/downloading the app?

Comment: I get push notifications absolutely fine when testing the app (using the development cert from apple and the dev provisioning profile that was created at the same time as the live prov profile).

Comment: You should be able to get APNS when testing but with the production cert, etc.